# Compare two fields in SQL to see if there are values in common

Tags: sql, t-sql

this is my first post so hopefully you great people out there will be able to help me please.

I have a data table with two columns of people's names. The names are pipe delimited.  I want to identify whether or not there are any names in common within those two columns with a True/False/Unknown output field appended for each row.  The result is 'Unknown' if one field is blank.

I am looking for an output like attached based on the two input columns.

[image: Names and result examples]

Is this possible to do in TSQL (we're running SQL database on Azure)?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The real problem here is that you're storing data in a delimited format; you need to fix that. Normalising your data will make things significantly easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running SQL Server 2016 or higher, one option uses `string_split()`:

```
select
    field1,
    field2
    case 
        when field1 is null or field2 is null 
            then 'Unknown'
        when exists (select 1 from string_split(field1, '|') where field2 like '%' + value + '%'    )
            then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end as result
from mytable
```

That said, your first effort should go into fixing your data model. Storing delimited lists in a table column basically defeats the purpose of a relational database, and should always be avoided. Each value should appear on a separate row.

Comment: Thank you GMB, that worked perfectly and I have learned a new function.  You are a star!

Comment: Since both delimited strings aren't being split this answer seems to have problem if one name is a substring of another, e.g. the string "Mr Ed" can be found in "Mrs Dry Crouton|Mr Edward Owen|Ms Alice Livemore", but it isn't a full match.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `split()` function, I would recommend `apply`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when names_in_common > 0 then 'true'
             when field1 is null or field2 is null then 'unknown'
             else 'false'
        end) as flag
from t outer apply
     (select count(*) as names_in_common
      from string_split(field1, '|') s1 join
           string_split(field2, '|') s2
           on s1.value = s2.value
     ) n
```